# Determining the Domain and Range of a multi-dimensional function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

$ f(x,y,z) = \frac{3}{2-x} + \frac{1}{y-z} $

i) Write down the domain of $f$

ii) Determine the range $T$ of $f$. For each $c \in T$ find a point $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f(x,y,z) = 1 $.

**My Answers:**

i) Domain: $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq 2, y \neq z$

ii) So $c = \frac{3}{2-x} + \frac{1}{y-z} \space \forall \space x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq 2, y \neq z  $

$ \iff \frac{3}{2-x} = c - \frac{1}{y-z} $

$ \iff \frac{3}{2-x} = \frac{c(y-z)-1}{y-z}$

$\iff x = \frac{-3(y-z)}{c(y-z)-1} + 2$

Do we then perform the above method on all 3 variables? Am I doing this correctly?

Is there any tiny minor details I left out, if so, can you let me know?

Thanks.

Comment: (i) Better form is to state $\text{Dom}(f)=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ :  x \neq 2,  \ y \neq z\}$

Comment: (ii)  Yes.  Your analysis is correct.  Depending on the level of rigor demanded,  you may want to verify that when $x=2 - \frac{3(y-z)}{c(y-z)-1},$  it follows that $x\neq 2.$   Also, you must choose $y,z$ such that $y-z \neq 1/c.$